# Dynamically search listbox using textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I have a database with some devices in it and I want to be able to dynamically search in my listbox, when typing in my textbox.
I tried some other suggestions on StackOverflow:
[Dynamic Search Result C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546256/dynamic-search-result-c-sharp)

So far I have this:

```
    List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();

    private void UpdateBindings()
    {
        deviceFoundListbox.DataSource = devices;
        deviceFoundListbox.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";
    }

    private void searchTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess database = new DataAccess();
        devices = database.GetDevice(searchTextbox.Text);
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            lastChange = DateTime.Now;
            textChanged = true;
        }
    }

    private void dynamicSearchTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            if(textChanged && lastChange > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-2))
            {
                UpdateBindings();
                textChanged = false;
                lastChange = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help's appreciated!

EDIT: The Device class:

```
internal class Device
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string LoanStatus { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }

    public string FullInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return $"Device: {DeviceName} S/N: {SerialNumber} Loaner Status: {LoanStatus} Initials: {Initials}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the result is assigned to `device`, but where does `devices` come from?

Comment: I've edited the post and added the Device class

Comment: You should probably add winforms or wpf tag, since it is not completely obvious from the context.

Comment: Filter already filled `ListBox` as you type in the `TextBox` **or** query the database for matches and populate the `ListBox`? Two different things. Your question suggests the former while the code suggests the later.

Comment: @dr.null I guess I should prepopulate the listbox with the devices and then only update the list when a new one is added or changed

Answer (score 0):

Result has been assigned to "device" and you are updating "devices" to DataSource?

How to assign :
device = database.GetDevice(searchTextbox.Text);
What return database.GetDevice();
If you have a device declaration when you add the devices list? or are you add device to devices?
You can use basically use `devices.Add(database.GetDevice());`